# How to properly store variable in a Loop in Bash?

Tags: bash, loops, scripting

May I ask how to loop in a while? he's my attempt on creating a file that will generate the data in a specific way. My aim is to append the rule into one single line, regardless of application number.

My Code is:

```
#!/bin/bash
file="temp3"
while IFS= read -r line
do
        # display $line or do somthing with $line
                #printf '%s\n' "$line"
                echo
                printf '%s\n' "$line" | grep "MySource" | awk '{printf " " $5}'
                printf '%s\n' "$line" | grep "MySource-" | awk '{printf " " $7 " " $8}'
                printf '%s\n' "$line" | grep "MyDestination" | awk '{printf " " $7 " " $8}'
                printf '%s\n' "$line" | grep "MyAppName" | awk '{printf " " $8}' #| awk '{printf " " $7 " " $8}'

                VARIABLE=$(printf '%s\n' "$line" | grep "source" | awk '{printf " " $5}')
                VARIABLE=$(printf '%s\n' "$line" | grep "source-" | awk '{printf " " $7 " " $8}')
                VARIABLE=$(printf '%s\n' "$line" | grep "destination" | awk '{printf " " $7 " " $8}')
                VARIABLE=$(printf '%s\n' "$line" | grep "application" | awk '{printf " " $8}')

                done <"$file"

echo $VARIABLE
printf $VARIABLE
```

here's the contents of my file

```
zone lab zone trust  new-rule-162 match source-address MySourceName1
zone lab zone trust  new-rule-162 match source-address MySourceName2
zone lab zone trust  new-rule-162 match destination-address MyDestinationName1
zone lab zone trust  new-rule-162 match destination-address MyDestinationName2
zone lab zone trust  new-rule-162 match application MyApplicationName1
zone lab zone trust  new-rule-162 match application MyApplicationName2
zone lab zone trust  new-rule-162 match application MyApplicationName3
zone lab zone trust  new-rule-162 then permit
```

Hopefully, ill be able to expand this in a way that I will be able to sort them out in the following manner.

```
new-rule-162 source-address MySourceName1 destination-address MyDestinationName1 application MyAppName1 MyAppName2 MyAppName3
```

The ultimate goal. In this case since, there are 2 sources and 2 destinations, the equivalent output should be 4 rows with all rows indicating the total X number of apps (4) and the permission "permit"

```
new-rule-162 source-address MySourceName1 destination-address MyDestinationName1 permit application MyAppName1 MyAppName2 MyAppName3 
new-rule-162 source-address MySourceName1 destination-address MyDestinationName2 permit application MyAppName1 MyAppName2 MyAppName3  
new-rule-162 source-address MySourceName2 destination-address MyDestinationName1 permit application MyAppName1 MyAppName2 MyAppName3 
new-rule-162 source-address MySourceName2 destination-address MyDestinationName2 permit application MyAppName1 MyAppName2 MyAppName3
```

Comment: There is nothing like `MyAppName`, `MySourceName1`, `MyDestinationName1`... in the inputs you show. Where do they come from? Please do not answer in comments, external pictures or web sites, simply edit your question and add the missing information. You could also visit the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help) and especially [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Your edit makes no improvement :-/. You are expected to describe the input file corrsonding to your ultimate goal. The input file should include `MySourceName1`, `MyDestinationName2 `, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code can help you to do it better

```
#!/bin/bash
while IFS=" " read -ra line; do
    # Set last Element equal to last element in array line avoid use awk
    lastElement=${line[-1]:-"Default value here"}

    echo "${line[4]} $lastElement ${line[-2]} where is the rest of the data ???"
# # For use a var here
# done <<<"$myVar"
done <log.txt
```

**The output is.**

```
new-rule-162 MySourceName source-address where is the rest of the data ???
new-rule-162 MyDestinationName destination-address where is the rest of the data ???
new-rule-162 MyApplicationName application where is the rest of the data ???
```

Note:
You don't need to print in order to grep, just do:
`grep -q "Some string" <<<"$line"`

```
if (grep -q "Some string" <<<"$line"); then
   Do some stuff     
fi
```

Or

```
(grep -q "Some text" <<<"$lone") && echo "Found" || echo "Not found"
```

Comment: Thank you for this. I will read this through and try it

Comment: Your welcome, we here to help you at anytime

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that the tags like `new-rule-162` are unique.

```
$ cat input-file

zone lab zone trust  new-rule-162 match source-address MySourceName
zone lab zone trust  new-rule-162 match destination-address MyDestinationName
zone lab zone trust  new-rule-162 match application MyApplicationName
zone lab zone trust  new-rule-162 then permit


$ awk '
    $(NF-1)=="source-address"{src[$5]=$NF}      # Record src; index by 5th field (new-rule-162)
    $(NF-1)=="destination-address"{dst[$5]=$NF} # and dest
    $(NF-1)=="application"{app[$5]=$NF}         # and app name
    END {
        for (i in src)                          # For all entries
            printf "%s source-address %s destination-address %s application %s\n", i, src[i], dst[i], app[i]; # print the required parameters
        }' input-file

new-rule-162 source-address MySourceName destination-address MyDestinationName application MyApplicationName
```

Comment: This is awesome. I did not know you can abuse awk like that.

It works but I would need to append more MyAppName's if they are more than 1.

Else, reprint per source and destination once again 

Something like
`source-address MySourceName1 destination-address MyDestinationName1 application MyApplicationName1 MyApplicationName2 

source-address MySourceName1 destination-address MyDestinationName2 application MyApplicationName1 MyApplicationName2 

source-address MySourceName2 destination-address MyDestinationName1 application MyApplicationName1 MyApplicationName2 
`

Comment: Change `$(NF-1)=="application"{app[$5]=$NF}` to `$(NF-1)=="application"{app[$5]=app[$5] " " $NF}`. Drop the space after `application` in the `printf` format string.